# Parallel load different objects in C# & .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Code snippet :

```
public override List<object> InitializeDependencies()
{
      return new List<object>
      {
          new CustomerPresenter(),
          new EmployeePresenter(),
          new SalaryPresenter()
      };
}
```

I want to invoke the dependent classes parallel. Is it possible ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I like the word you made up: parallely.

Comment: If you are trying to speed up loading the dependencies try using Lazy<T> so that they are initialized only when used.

Comment: No Raj. I want eager load.

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly shorter than tym32167's solution:

```
public override List<object> InitializeDependencies() {
  var tasks = new[] { 
    Task.Run<object>(()=>new CustomerPresenter()),
    Task.Run<object>(()=>new EmployeePresenter()),
    Task.Run<object>(()=>new SalaryPresenter())
  };
  return tasks.Select(x=>x.Result).ToList();
}
```

It is not necessary to call `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` since the access to the Result properties does this implicitly. However, the generation of the tasks must be separated from the generation of the returned list.

Comment: I know that Task.WaitAll(tasks); is not necessary, but with this code will be a little bit more clean for understanding, because you exactly know when current thread will be blocked and how many times. Without it current thread will be blocked up to three times while calculating results. Moreover, if somwhen return type will be swithched from List to Enumerable, and developer will remove .ToList() from return value, you cannot determine when and how many times current thread will be blocked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public override List<object> InitializeDependencies()
{
    var tasks = new[] 
    { 
        Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(()=>new CustomerPresenter()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(()=>new EmployeePresenter()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(()=>new SalaryPresenter()),
    };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    return tasks.Select(x=>x.Result).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tym32167 and MarkusParker. I have created a demo may be useful for others :

```
 public class ParallelLoad
{
    public List<object> Initialize()
    {
        var tasks = new[] { 
            Task.Run<object>(()=>new Customer()),
            Task.Run<object>(()=>new Employee()),
            Task.Run<object>(()=>new Address())
          };

        return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList();

        //return new List<object>
        //{
        //    new Customer(),
        //    new Employee(),
        //    new Address()
        //};
    }
}

class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer: " + i);
        }
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee: " + i);
        }
    }
}

class Address
{
    public Address()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Address: " + i);
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ParallelLoadTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Given_When_Then()
    {
        // Arrange
        var presenter = new ParallelLoad();

        // Act
        presenter.Initialize();

        // Assert

    }
}
```